# How to get unicode string from cocoa keyDown event?

Tags: objective-c

I had read cocoa Key Event Handling docs. And get a code snippet example like following:
The question is when I change my input method other than English (like Chinese). The Code snippet doesn't works, it still return a single alphabetic character but not a unicode chinese character. Any Suggestion or I missing some part of the documents?

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [self interpretKeyEvents:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theEvent]];
}

// The following action methods are declared in NSResponder.h
- (void)insertTab:(id)sender
{
    if ([[self window] firstResponder] == self)
    {
        [[self window] selectNextKeyView:self];
    }
}


- (void)insertBacktab:(id)sender
{
    if ([[self window] firstResponder] == self)
    {
        [[self window] selectPreviousKeyView:self];
    }
}

- (void)insertText:(id)string
{
    [super insertText:string];  // have superclass insert it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the default implementation (`[NSEvent characters]`? `charactersIgnoringModifiers`?) is not working, you could try accessing the value via the event's `@property CGEvent`, then see if you get the result you want using something like `CGEventKeyboardGetUnicodeString`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're capturing text in an `NSTextView` (which I guess you are, since you have `-insertText:`), then you can use the `NSTextViewDelegate` to capture Unicode input.

For example, implement `[NSTextViewDelegate textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:]`.

Unlike `NSEvent`, which operates at the level of keystrokes, this method operates at the higher level of Unicode characters.